# Ruby: Get first few files from directory?

Tags: ruby, break, glob

How do I just grab the first N files from a directory?

I've tried iterating through the files via

```
Dir.glob(expression).do |f|
   i = i + 1
   files.push(f)

   if (i == 5) then
      break  # illegal
   end
end
```

but putting `break` inside the `then` clause is apparently illegal.

Thanks!

Comment: Oops...love programming in terminal emulators at night.

It's `Dir.glob(expression) do` not `Dir.glob(expression).do`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Dir.glob(expression).first(5)
```

This will take first 5 files from a directory.

Comment: I suppose this is a much cleaner approach. :)

Answer (score 2):

Is this acceptable:

```
MAX = 5
Dir.glob(expression)[0..MAX-1]
```

Comment: Looks like a nice shortcut, but does that integrate with `do |f|` ?

Comment: You don't have to enter the `do` loop, just `files = Dir.glob(expression)[0..MAX-1]`

Comment: Don't use `[0..MAX-1]`, use `[0, MAX]`.